# Proper div sizing without using pixel values

Tags: html, css

My case is as follows. I have a div with two children divs. I'd like the 'event' div to be 300px of width and height. First requirement is to keep the size of the 'event' div when 'content' and 'bar' elements use 100% of parent's width. Secondly as for now, borders of 'content' element are not visible. Is it possible to fit everything inside without using hardcoded values and get this display properly in most of the modern browsers (FF, Chrome, Opera, IE7+) ?

This is what I'd like to achieve (notice the left red bar which takes 100% height and doesn't collide with the grey border around the event element):

[image]

And this is what I have. Html :

[image]

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scheduler">
        <div class="event" style="top: 30px; height: 300px; width: 300px">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="inner-content">Some text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

, css :

```
#wrapper {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
}
#scheduler {
    background-color: #E1FFFE;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#scheduler .event {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#scheduler .event .bar {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 5px;
}
#scheduler .event .content {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and a runnable demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/6nTvD/1/

Comment: I very much appreciate the provided jsFiddle! Unfortunately however, reading through your question quickly, I'm unable to understand your desired results, or how your current jsFiddle isn't satisfying. Are you trying to preserve the borders?

Comment: yes, show the borders but keep the 'event' div 300x300. If the 'overflow:hidden' is removed, borders are visible but the size is increased.

Comment: Perhaps look into `box-sizing:border-box;`??

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Take out the `bar` div, then change the `.content` css to:

```
#scheduler .event .content {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-left: 5px solid red; // replaces the bar
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 99%; // a bit of a hack to fit the border in
    position: relative;
    width: 98%; // hack
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dp3yz/

EDIT: Code with the `.bar` still in place:

```
#scheduler .event .bar {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 99.9%; /* Small offset at bottom */
    position: relative;
    width: 5px;
}
#scheduler .event .content {
    background-color: white;

    /* revised border */
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 99%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 98%;
}
```

New version:
http://jsfiddle.net/JJrC9/1/

Comment: I feel pretty certain that the desired outcomes can be achieved without any form of hacks, and that all of this code can be vastly simplified -- I'm too busy though, and don't really understand the desired outcomes enough to proceed anways, more work would go in to trying to decode what the OP actually means. If it were explained better in the original question, I feel like we'd all have no problem creating a solution that only spans a handful of lines in CSS :/
+1 to your answer though for providing the best SO can in this situation.

Comment: if I'll replace the bar with a border, the top border and left borders will collide which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think I fully understand your quandary, however,* with the only difference I can spy between your desired outcome and your current work being the presence of the borders -- switching `overflow:hidden;` on `#scheduler .event` to `overflow:visible;` produces something that visually looks to me like it achieves the desired affect.

Comment: yes, but the size is increased (not the calculated size, at least in firebug, but visually it exceeds the original boundaries)